# ORACL PL/SQL Trigger Using Two different tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am not experienced in PL/SQL topics a lot, besides writing migration SQLs and some basic triggers. Because of that i will ask my question directly to have at least one start point into my trigger for table that i am expecting.

We have below tables :

[image]
[image]

```
VIB: Varchar
Locale: Varchar
Status : Varchar
Released : boolean
```

I need a trigger on `D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_MASTER` table, the requirement is that, some system will give inserts to this table for "vib" column ***without LOCALE values for vibs***. So our expectation is to calculate locales(find appropriate locales from release_table) before insert operation of that system, by asking `RELEASE_TABLE` for appropriate locales that is existing for that `VIB`, and released flag is 'true'.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BL_D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_MASTER
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_MASTER
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_locale  varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    if :NEW.locale is null then
    for rec in (select locale from RELEASE_TABLE@pdpe.mch.bshg.com where vib=:NEW.vib AND released = 1)
    loop
    INSERT INTO d2c_event_generation_master (vib,locale) VALUES (:NEW.vib,rec.locale);
    end loop;
    DELETE FROM d2c_event_generation_master where vib=:NEW.vib AND locale is null;
    end if;
END;
```

I am about to create this trigger, but only one exception occurs that i couldn't fix. When i insert a row with null locale value in table like this :

```
  INSERT INTO D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_AP (vib) values ('GP200046');
```

It gets locales from other table but inserts three rows :

```
GP200046    fr-BE
GP200046    nl-BE
GP200046    null
```

I don't want to see 'null' here, i tried some execute immediate or some other staff, but couldn't find something.

Can you please help there ?

Comment: what sort of calculation do you do for LOCALE? is it a math calculation of are you retrieving data from another table?

Comment: Imagine that, it is just a query like "select vib from release_table where released = true" and for the response locales i should create insert or update to other table by usage of these locales.

Comment: So if I understand correctly someone will insert only primary key D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_MASTER table without locale and then you will need to query the RELEASE table to get the locale values joining the two tables using the VIB column, am I right?

Comment: Exactly! Release table will give the necessary locales to me, these tables can be easily joined using VIB column.

Comment: Ok then a trigger is the way to go, for the second one, you want to very first than a row with VIB and locale doesn't already exists in the table with a status different of NEW, if it's the case then you will just update the status to NEW?

Comment: It might exist in table with different STATUS value than 'NEW', in that condition we will only update the status to NEW, if it doesn't exist, make regular insert.

Comment: Edited my answer for the second part, it should work but you have to test it.

Comment: New edit for the second solution, tested and working.

Answer (score 2):

here is a trigger before insert to get value from the release table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BI_D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_MASTER
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_MASTER
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_locale   varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    if :NEW.locale is null then
        select locale INTO l_locale from release where vib=:NEW.vib;
        :NEW.locale := l_locale;
    end if;
END;
/
```

**EDIT:**

For the second solution I suggest creating a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MI_D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_MASTER (p_vib number, p_locale varchar2)
IS
 l_vib number := p_vib;
 l_locale varchar2(100) := p_locale;
BEGIN   
    MERGE INTO D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_MASTER event
    USING (SELECT vib, locale from D2C_EVENT_GENERATION_MASTER) old_event
    ON (event.vib = l_vib
        and event.locale = l_locale)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET event.STATUS = 'NEW'
        WHERE event.STATUS != 'NEW'
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (vib,locale,status) VALUES (l_vib, l_locale, 'STATUS')';
END;
/
```

Comment: Why dynamic SQL?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson you're right, no need, I updated the answer.

Comment: The trigger is still dynamic.

Comment: Hi guys, if possible, can you check my edit ? Regarding to deletion of null value from table ? Also answer was not covering multiple row condition, i edited loop to use that on my question.